# Eclipse debug mode when using Javafx

Tags: eclipse, debugging, javafx

When I use JavaFX in Eclipse debug mode with a breakpoint, it is not running to the breakpoint whereas it is showing `URLClassLoader` class:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a [Java Exception Breakpoint](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-catching_exceptions.htm) (see _Breakpoints_ view) which pauses the main thread because of a thrown `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: i unchecked "ClassNotFoundException". now i am able to passs thru debug mode. I didn't understand why it was giving such an exception? Thank you.

Comment: It was attempted to load a class that does not exist. But obviously, the class is not mandatory. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a **[Java Exception Breakpoint](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-catching_exceptions.htm)** which pauses the main thread because of a thrown `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

To disable it, go to the ***Breakpoints*** view, find and **uncheck** the exception breakpoint.

Note, a thrown exception does not necessarily mean that an unpredictable error has occurred, but only the `catch` branch of the surrounding `try`-`catch` statement will be executed somewhere inside the application or in a library.